# extension that can only be applied on a given class type

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a Protocol that only subclasses of UIView can conform to.

Is there a way to do that?

---

```swift
// The Protocol
protocol MyProtocol {
    func someMethod()
}

// This works fine
class MyView: UIView, MyProtocol {
    func someMethod()
}

// I want this to throw a compiler error
// Since it is *not* a subclass of UIView
class MyObject: NSObject, MyProtocol {
    func someMethod()
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? If a type can satisfy the requirements of `MyProtocol`, why shouldn't it be allowed to conform?

Comment: This answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501965/3141421

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Create an additional protocol `UIViewType`, make `UIView` conform to that protocol and constrain `MyProtocol` to `UIViewType` :

   ```
   protocol UIViewType {}

   extension UIView : UIViewType {}

   protocol MyProtocol : UIViewType {}
   ```
2. Use a protocol extension:

   ```
   protocol MyProtocol {}

   extension MyProtocol where Self : UIView {}
   ```

Comment: Note that neither of these options actually *prevent* a type from conforming to `MyProtocol` unless they're a `UIView`. With the first option, the type could also conform itself to `UIViewType`. With your second option, I fail to see how it would even work – protocol extensions don't restrict the conformance to a protocol, they just let you add default implementations.