# How to create constraint on protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I tried to create protocol which can be only implemented by classes which inherit from `UIView`, what was my surprise when this code compiles without errors (in Swift 3.0):

```
protocol TestsProtocol {
    func test()
}

extension TestsProtocol where Self: UIView { }

class FooClass: TestsProtocol {

    func test() {

    }
}
```

We can see that `FooClass` don't inherit from `UIView`, using protocol extension I wan't to force that only classes which inherit from `UIView` can implement it.
As far as I remember this would not compile in Swift 2.1

Comment: I can't think of a reason for why this wouldn't compile in Swift 2.1 – protocol extensions don't restrict what types can conform to a protocol, they just let you add default implementations. But the real question is if a type *can* meet all the protocol's requirements, why *shouldn't* it be allowed to conform unless it's also a `UIView`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extension that can only be applied on a given class type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349324/extension-that-can-only-be-applied-on-a-given-class-type) – although I don't believe the answer there achieves *exactly* what you want. The answer is simply you cannot restrict the conformance to a protocol based on the conforming type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in Swift. The extension syntax does something else:

```
extension TestsProtocol where Self: UIView {
    func useful() {
        // do something useful
    }
}
```

now any class which implements TestsProtocol and is a UIView (or subclass) also has the useful() function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily by limit protocol from be extendable from any type other than UIView :

```
protocol TestsProtocol:UIView {
    func test()
}

class FooClass: TestsProtocol {

    func test() {

    }
}
```

So this will cause compile error

> 'TestsProtocol' requires that 'FooClass' inherit from 'UIView'